# How to dynamically change from Hamburger icon to Up icon in Appcompat 22

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I would like to change a Hamburger icon in ToolBar to Up icon ("<") given a user input within a same Activity.

This is my ToolBar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle">
```

on `MainActivity#onCreate`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This will show a Hamburger icon, although the documentation states "Set whether home should be displayed as an "up" affordance".
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)

In my event callback, I call

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

However it does not show an Up icon; instead Hamburger icon is still shown.
I am confused as it does seem like it is conflicting with the documentation.
Is there any way I can switch between a hamburger icon and an up icon in the toolBar within a same activity based on an user event?

Here is my reference to support libraries in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
```

It is also worth noting that my `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I am having the same problem with this as well. It seems to have happened with the 22 update because it was working fine before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppCompt 22 they messed up on the main theme. Also getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); now longer does anything at all. Unless you are supporting legacy I would highly recommend not using `setSupportActionbar` and just do all of your calls directly on the toolbar. That is now the correct way of handling it.

To fix the theme bug add the navigationIcon to your theme. You can also do it directly to the toolbar, but then you'll have to handle it on a case by case basis.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
    </style>
```

Your next going to want use the [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) with your navigationDrawer, **the V7 one NOT the V4**. This is really stupidly name as it is now just supposed to be used with the toolbar. I won't show you how to set it up here because there are plenty of examples else where.

Your going to need to `setToolbarNavigationClickListener` on your drawerToggle that you just made. This listener will be called when your toggle is deactivated, which I will talk about after this. Here I just use the `onBackPressed()`, a method on your activity, if the user clicks the navigationIcon aka back arrow.

```
    drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

It is now super easy to dynamically switch between the two. If you want the hamburger icon shown and it to control your navigation drawer then `drawerToogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`. If you want it to show the navigationIcon and have the above listener get called on a press then call `drawerToogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`.

Comment: I think something is not correct here, may be a typo mistake. The tool bar click listener must be on the Tool Bar not on Drawer Toggle. Here is the correct version :


    mToolBar.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        } 
    });